# Django render redirects to /. . . (3 dots)

Tags: python, django

I have the below view function in my code:

```
def view_candidate(request, candidate_id):
        print "id" +candidate_id
        return render(request, 'core/reports.html')
```

When i access this page, i get the below redirection in log

```
view_candidate
id2
[15/Mar/2016 18:10:52]"GET /candidate/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 1454
view_candidate
id...
[15/Mar/2016 18:10:52]"GET /candidate/... HTTP/1.1" 200 1454
```

It prints the id and redirects to `candidate/...` which is not expected. It is happening for all my render functions.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^home/$', views.home, name="home"),
    url(r'^candidate/(?P<candidate_id>.*)/review/{0,1}$', views.review_candidate, name="review_candidate"),
    url(r'^candidate/(?P<candidate_id>.*)/{0,1}$', views.view_candidate, name="view_candidate"),
    url(r'^candidate/$', views.add_candidate, name="candidates"),
    url(r'^reports/$', views.reports, name="reports"),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name="login"),

]
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add what is inside your urls.py.

Comment: What do you mean "redirects to `/candidate/...`" ? I see no redirection, status code is 200. `/candidate/...` is probably called by your browser. Check the network tab of your browser, and eventually the rendered HTML code to see if there is any call to a resource named `/candidate/...`.

Comment: Its not redirection, but render function calls that url. How can browser call somethinh which is not in my code? I even tested with a hello world html.

Comment: I've written my suspicions in an answer. If it's correct, feel free to mark it as an answer for your question.

Comment: Best would be to try outside of your browser. With curl for instance. What is the output of `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/candidate/2` (assuming your server runs on 127.0.0.1:8000) and do you get that `GET /candidate/...` in the logs?

Comment: Yes it is showing up even if i use curl. The log which i have given in the question is for a single request to candidates/2 which prints 'id2' and somehow it is again calling candidates/... From the render function. If i use Httpresponse instead of render, it works fine.

Comment: Could you then add code of your views.py to the question?

Answer (score -1):

Most probably in `core/reports.html` you have a form, which have three dots as value of `action` attribute. Like:

```
<form action="...">
  …
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When you hit the submit button, it routes you to `/candidate/...`.

Or you have some link with `<a href="...">` which when clicked causes that request.

Get to know more about forms on [HTML Forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) and [Working with forms in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/) documentation.

Comment: Then it would be a POST request, unless the `method` attribute of the `form` element is set to "get", in which case there would be a querystring part in the URI. And it's not the case.

Comment: I don't have a problem with form submit. This is general to view functions which returns with render.